# Searching a tool to visualize memory

Tags: console, software-rec

I am searching a program which can show the memory as a colorful grid in console.
For example showing used, unused and changed stuff.
This is not for monitoring, its simply for a screen which is sitting on top of a server, and I would like it to display something fancy.

I remember having seen such a tool years ago, but I cannot find it, seems my search keywords are bad (linux visualize memory screensaver console).

Comment: You may be looking for [htop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop).

Answer (score 2):

> This is not for monitoring, its simply for a screen which is sitting
>   on top of a server, and I would like it to display something fancy.

Have a look at [Glances](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/). I have used this for various purposes and am quite happy with it.

Comment: looks good, but not colorful enough .. hehe, but its very informative - maybe I will keep it.